# planning_model package build fails: oneric

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-oneiric, arm-navigation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I m trying to build armnavigation stack of ros electric. in ubuntu oneiric using gcc4.6. but i ran into the following errors:

> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:251:37:
> error: wrong number of template
> arguments (1, should be 3)
> /usr/include/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:90:64:
> error: provided for ‘template<class
> Key, class Compare, class Allocator>
> struct std::set’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:251:49:
> error: invalid type in declaration
> before ‘it’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:251:49:
> error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:251:49:
> error: ‘it’ was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:251:64:
> error: request for member ‘begin’ in
> ‘joint_set’, which is of non-class
> type ‘int’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:252:27:
> error: request for member ‘end’ in
> ‘joint_set’, which is of non-class
> type ‘int’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:252:32:
> error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:251:40:
> warning: unused variable ‘iterator’
> [-Wunused-variable]
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:253:11:
> error: ‘it’ was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:253:15:
> error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:
> In member function
> ‘planning_models::KinematicModel::LinkModel*
> planning_models::KinematicModel::constructLinkModel(const
> urdf::Link*)’:
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:422:23:
> error: ‘ROS_ASSERT’ was not declared
> in this scope
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:
> In member function ‘shapes::Shape*
> planning_models::KinematicModel::constructShape(const
> urdf::Geometry*)’:
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:453:18:
> error: ‘ROS_ASSERT’ was not declared
> in this scope
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:
> In constructor
> ‘planning_models::KinematicModel::JointModelGroup::JointModelGroup(const
> string&, const std::vector<const
> planning_models::KinematicModel::JointModel*>&,
> const std::vector<const
> planning_models::KinematicModel::JointModel*>&,
> const
> planning_models::KinematicModel*)’:
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1264:28:
> error: wrong number of template
> arguments (1, should be 3)
> /usr/include/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:90:64:
> error: provided for ‘template<class
> Key, class Compare, class Allocator>
> struct std::set’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1264:45:
> error: invalid type in declaration
> before ‘;’ token
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1268:21:
> error: request for member ‘insert’ in
> ‘group_links_set’, which is of
> non-class type ‘int’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1275:23:
> error: request for member ‘insert’ in
> ‘group_links_set’, which is of
> non-class type ‘int’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1281:32:
> error: wrong number of template
> arguments (1, should be 3)
> /usr/include/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:90:64:
> error: provided for ‘template<class
> Key, class Compare, class Allocator>
> struct std::set’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1281:44:
> error: invalid type in declaration
> before ‘it’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1281:44:
> error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1281:44:
> error: ‘it’ was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1281:65:
> error: request for member ‘begin’ in
> ‘group_links_set’, which is of
> non-class type ‘int’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1282:29:
> error: request for member ‘end’ in
> ‘group_links_set’, which is of
> non-class type ‘int’
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1282:34:
> error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1281:35:
> warning: unused variable ‘iterator’
> [-Wunused-variable]
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1283:7:
> error: ‘it’ was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1283:11:
> error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/src/kinematic_model.cpp:1309:1:
> error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
> make[3]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/planning_models.dir/src/kinematic_model.o]
> Error 1   make[3]: Leaving directory
> `/home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/planning_models.dir/all] Error 2   make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/build'
> make[1]: *** [all] Error 2   make[1]:
> Leaving directory
> `/home/pragyan/tredext/biome/armnavigation/planning_models/build'
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of
> package planning_models written to: [
> rosmake ]
> /home/pragyan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111201-131855/planning_models/build_output.log
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<<
> planning_models [FAIL] [ 6.85 seconds
> ]
> [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in
> package planning_models.  [ rosmake ]
> Waiting for other threads to complete.
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 25 packages with 1
> failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to
> directory
> [ rosmake ]
> /home/pragyan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111201-131855

could any body please tell me what should i do to make it work.
Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12170/planning_model-package-build-fails:-oneric/) by [pntripathi9417](https://answers.ros.org/users/1369/pntripathi9417/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the clue:

```
‘ROS_ASSERT’ was not declared in this scope
```

So just include the header *ros/assert.h* that declares ROS_ASSERT in the offending file

```
Index: src/kinematic_model.cpp
===================================================================
--- src/kinematic_model.cpp     (revision 54435)
+++ src/kinematic_model.cpp     (working copy)
@@ -39,6 +39,7 @@
 #include <resource_retriever/retriever.h>
 #include <queue>
 #include <ros/console.h>
+#include <ros/assert.h>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <angles/angles.h>
 #include <assimp/assimp.hpp>
```

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2